# Swift call prepareForSegue after cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistoryboardsegue

I have a segue tied to a table view. I need to figure out which cell was tapped in prepareForSegue so I can extract the info for that cell and pass it to the destination view controller. How do I do that?

Edit:
Code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    print ("preparingForSeque...")
    if (segue.identifier == "quoteView") {
        let svc = segue.destinationViewController as! QuoteViewController
        svc.category = clickedCategory
        print ("svc.category is now " + clickedCategory)
        print ("Preparing for transfer to a quoteView")
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    clickedCategory = categoryArray[indexPath.row]
    print ("cell clicked, clickedCategory is now " + clickedCategory)
}
```

Comment: If you call `tableView.reloadData()`, all cells will be reloaded and `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` will be called for each visible cell. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: You don't call cellForRowAtIndexPath. The system calls that method when the table view needs to be updated. You mean that you want your table view to update before you trigger a segue? Tell us what you are trying to do at a high level.

Comment: I'm attempting to display data in a new ViewController based on the cell clicked, and I'm transferring data between two classes whenever a cell is clicked. However, when I click the cell, prepareForSegue is called before the value I'm needing to transfer changes (therefore the value isn't correct)

Comment: @SausageMachine I'm never calling cellForRowAtIndex path myself. I totally understand the XY problem scenario, please refrain from calling my solution 'hideous' especially when I haven't made a solution in the first place.

Comment: Sausage Machine speaks truth. You are badly confused. Cells don't store data, they present data. If you are trying to read data from the cell, you are doing it wrong. You probably want to implement the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` table view delegate method, and invoke your segue through code from that method. Again, we can't help you unless you step back from your (badly flawed) idea of how to implement your app idea, and tell us what you want your app to do in terms of high-level function.

Comment: Why is the value changing at all?

Comment: @SausageMachine, terms like "hideous" and "horrendous" are needlessly insulting. Avoid value judgements and stick to the facts.

Comment: @DuncanC, updated post with code.

Comment: What is triggering your segue?

Comment: You can get use `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()` in `prepareForSegue` to get the index of the cell they selected and get your data.

Comment: @DuncanC Whenever I click on a cell, my segue is called.

Comment: @dan Thanks, case closed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `tableView.reloadData()` if you want to reload the whole tableview and if you want to go to a view controller after pressing on a cell use func name `tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`.

Answer (score 0):

"You can get use tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() in prepareForSegue to get the index of the cell they selected and get your data." Solution by dan in the comments.

Comment: So the real question was "I have a segue tied to a table view. I need to figure out which cell was tapped in `prepareForSegue` so I can extract the info for that cell and pass it to the destination view controller. How do I do that?" You should edit your original question to make it clear what you were asking.